# StartService error 2

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, windows-10

I've written a very simple batch file that bluescreens windows 7 (ultimate,enterprise,home) beyond normal repair, by making an attempt of loading a Win32 exe-file (the well known notepad.exe) into the operating system's kernel. Feel free to test it in a Virtual Machine, just open it as an administrator. Do NOT run this as administrator on your primary computer.

```
@echo off
sc create bluescreener binpath = C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe type= filesys start= boot
sc start bluescreener
timeout /t 30
```

However: When I run this program on windows 10, it successfully creates the service, but it doesn't start. Instead it returns the following error:
[SC] StartService Failed 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

It is referring to the binpath I set in the batch file. I am sure this path exists, and that this is the exact path name. I don't understand why it can't find the file. I have tried using backslashes instead of forward-slashes, and that didn't work either. (I have forward-slashes because I have a python program that writes this batch file, and the line break in python uses a backslash, and that conflicts with the path.)

I tried the "sc qc bluescreener" test that shows information about the service I have created. This is what comes up. (It is the same thing that comes up when I test it on windows 7, where it works.)

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: bluescreener
        TYPE               : 2  FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 0   BOOT_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : \SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : bluescreener
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :
```

I can't find any explanation for why it can't find the file.
When I try to reboot windows 10 after creating the service, it can't boot, which means that the service is probably working and that the file was located.  I just want to know why Windows 7 can find the file and immediately bluescreens, while Windows 10 can't find the file and needs to be rebooted for the service to run.

Any suggestions on how I might reproduce the same effect i get on Windows 7, but on Windows 10?

Comment: Try using `start=demand`

Comment: I tried start=demand, but nothing changed. Could you elaborate on why that might help? I don't know much about sc start arguments...